# Replace statement using roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to update a statment in my file. my requirement is to update

```
protected override void OnLaunchApplication(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("Hub", null);
    }
```

to

```
protected override void OnLaunchApplication(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
    }
```

I am using following code:

```
 // read file contents
            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(targetFile);

            // create syntax tree
            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(fileContent);

            // locate OnLaunchApplication event
            var targetMethod =
                tree.GetRoot()
                    .DescendantNodes()
                    .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Identifier.Value == "OnLaunchApplication");

            if (targetMethod != null)
            {
                StatementSyntax oldSyntax = targetMethod.DescendantNodes()
                    .OfType<StatementSyntax>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString() == @"NavigationService.Navigate(""Hub"", null);");

                StatementSyntax newHubSyntax = Syntax.ParseStatement(@"NavigationService.Navigate(""Main"", null);");

                CompilationUnitSyntax newRoot = tree.GetRoot().ReplaceNode(oldSyntax, newHubSyntax);

                File.WriteAllText(targetFile, newRoot.ToFullString());
            }
```

but the result of the above is:

```
 protected override void OnLaunchApplication(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);        }
```

the statement starts from the left and even "}" bracket comes on the same line.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to copy the `SyntaxTrivia` from the old statement to the new one.

BTW: It would probably be better to do a weaker check for the node you want to replace, and to replace only the `LiteralExpressionSyntax` for "Hub". Otherwise any white space in the original will mess you up, and you will remove any other formatting/comments/etc in the statement you are replacing.

Comment: can you put code as you mentioned LiteralExpression